# Why does this programmer in particular passes pointers in functions by reference?

Tags: c++

I saw this particular code:

```
void GetMe(User& user) {
     std::cout << user.getName() << std::endl;
}

main(...) {
     User* user = new User("Joe");
     GetMe(*user);
     getchar();
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I cannot find an example for this in particular on any question here on Stack overflow only some with (&*) instead of (&) and I don't understand what is the point behind it, is it for safety in case the pointer is deleted somewhere else ? (It's a multi threaded app)

Comment: I cannot see a pointer by reference, but just a (useless) reference parameter that should be `const` in this case. That code isn't very good, and certainly shouldn't be taken as a reference for a common idiom.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not the reference, but the pointer is useless. The object could well be created on the stack.

Comment: He must have done it to keep Joe alive when he goes out of scope.

Comment: References don't add any _thread safety_ BTW.

Comment: If I understand the question here, the `&*` is just an aside about the fact that the title of this question gets you to a different question in which `&*` is being discussed.  That just means the title of this question is a poor hint at what this question is asking.  I think we still know what this question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a user defined type to a function, you can use one of the following approaches:

1. Pass by value:

   ```
   void GetMe(User user) { ... }
   ```
2. Pass by pointer:

   ```
   void GetMe(User* userPtr) { ... }
   void GetMe(User const* userPtr) { ... }
   ```
3. Pass by reference:

   ```
   void GetMe(User& user) { ... }
   void GetMe(User const& userPtr) { ... }
   ```

As a rule of thumb, passing by reference is preferable to passing by value or passing by pointer.

When you pass by reference instead of by value, the cost of copying an object is avoided.

When you pass by pointer, you cannot assume that a `nullptr` won't be passed. So, you have add checks in `GetMe` to account for that case. You don't worry about that when you pass by reference.

Comment: How I am tired of those advices, coming straight from 1998. 'Passing by reference is preferred...' It is NOT preferred as a rule of thumb.

Comment: @SergeyA, do you have any basis to justify your claim? The last I checked, Item 22 from Effective C++ is still valid.

Comment: Nowdays, you have a lot of new options with `std::unique_ptr` or even `std::shared_ptr`, not to mention universal references in templates. However, as far as I am concerned, the rule of thumb is still as good as ever: pass "big" objects by `const&` to avoid copies, pass primitive types or "primitive-like" types such as iterators by value. AFAIK the famous "want speed, pass by value" article is already considered outdated by the community. That's how fast C++ is moving forward these days :)

Comment: @sergeya passing unique or shared ptrs represents transferring/expanding ownership respectively. References aren't an alternative to shared or unique, but to plain pointers and they still fulfill that role in C++xyz

Comment: @SergeyA:  Passing by reference guarantees that the object exists.  Passing by pointer has the option of the pointer being NULL or the pointer pointing to an invalid location, including incorrect objects.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, who told you so? foo(int& i); int i*; foo(*i);. Where is the guarantee?

Comment: @SergeyA: Note that in `foo(*i)` that the deferencing occurs *before* the first statement in the function is executed.  Depending on the compiler, the dereferencing may occur before the function is called.  So, within the function, there needs no pointer validity checking.

Comment: It doesn't matter. All I am saying is that 'reference guarantees object validity' is an old computer sciences professors tale.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking why the code wasn't written as:

```
void GetMe(User* user) {
     std::cout << user->getName() << std::endl;
}

main(...) {
     User* user = new User("Joe");
     GetMe(user);
     getchar();
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But a lot of experienced programmers would instead ask why it wasn't.

```
void GetMe(User const& user) {
     std::cout << user.getName() << std::endl;
}

main(...) {
     User* user = new User("Joe");
     GetMe(*user);
     getchar();
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In both examples, I am ignoring the more serious issue of the memory leaking non-smart pointer and just looking at how user is passed to GetMe.

The original vs. the way I think you are asking about is largely a style question.  I don't see a multi-threading or other functional difference (as you asked about) nor a strong argument for either style.

But I do see strong arguments for tagging it `const` when passed either by pointer or reference.  If `getName()` is not `const` (causing it to be harder to make user const) then that likely should also be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, there are two parts to your question:

1. Why the interface, `void GetMe(User& user) { }` instead of `void GetMe(User* user) {}`?  There can be several reasons:

   `void GetMe(User& user) { }` implies a malleable **non-null** **input** and **output** `user`.  If you want non-malleable or **input-only**, use `void GetMe(User const& user) { }`.  If you want nullable, use pointers, etc...

How you pass parameters in C++ has very specific semantics, so you must be careful how you do it.  They all have different meanings: passing by reference, by pointer, by const reference, by const pointer, etc...

2. Why `User* user = new User("Joe");` instead of `User user("Joe");`?  There may be reasons why you want to allocate memory dynamically on the heap rather than locally on the stack.  For example, if you want the lifetime of the object to be longer than the closing brace.  Another reason used to be that if `User` is a really large object, then you want it on the heap (with modern CPUs, this may be less of an issue).

Note that **multi-threading** is an entirely different can of worms.  You have to worry about memory visibility, synchronisation, mutexes, race conditions, etc...  ...most of those issues are orthogonal to the two points above.  I recommend that you get a good handle basic C++ semantics before you head down that road, if you don't want to end up wasting a ton of time debugging threading problems.

Answer (score -2):

By  default, parameters pass by value to function, i.e.without & , you have a copy of your parameter  in function - just copy of  its value ,not its reference- i.e. you don't have your real parameter in function and if you have to do some operations with address(refrence) of parameters, everything going to wrong.

Consider this example: a function that could not be to allocate memory to its parameter (char) :

```
void al(char * c) //wrong way: pass by value
{
c =new char[10];
}
main()
{
char * x;
al(x);//don't allocated because pass by value/.
 *x='a';//memory error//
 }
```

but this function declaration can do this because pass by reference:

```
 void al(char * & c)
```

Comment: Couldn't write a worse answer, even if I try real hard.

Comment: @SergeyA read again,pleas